# Django 1.3 test errors: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm getting a bunch of test errors in my django project.  They are caused by adding 'django.contrib.messages' to INSTALLED_APPS.  Has anyone seen these before?

```
# python manage.py test
........................................................................
........................................................................
..............................EEE......................EEE..............
.............EEE.....................EEE........
======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.cookie.CookieTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 284, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently (django.contrib.messages.tests.cookie.CookieTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 313, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_auth_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.cookie.CookieTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 250, in test_middleware_disabled_auth_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.fallback.FallbackTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 284, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently (django.contrib.messages.tests.fallback.FallbackTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 313, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_auth_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.fallback.FallbackTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 250, in test_middleware_disabled_auth_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.user_messages.LegacyFallbackTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 284, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently (django.contrib.messages.tests.user_messages.LegacyFallbackTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 313, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_auth_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.user_messages.LegacyFallbackTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 250, in test_middleware_disabled_auth_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.session.SessionTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 284, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently (django.contrib.messages.tests.session.SessionTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 313, in test_middleware_disabled_anon_user_fail_silently
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

======================================================================
ERROR: test_middleware_disabled_auth_user (django.contrib.messages.tests.session.SessionTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/so/Code/freshplum/env/orchard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/tests/base.py", line 250, in test_middleware_disabled_auth_user
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've added the app to `INSTALLED_APPS`, but you haven't added the relevant context processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` - it needs to include `"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"`.